# implementing small directory tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I have an assignment to implement a binary directory tree

we have to use enumeration with labels Folder and File

we have to define type struct FOLDER with elements: name which is a dynamically string, left and right pointer to the structure and identifier which is type enum

we have to define struct FILE with elements name identifier and int data

the part above is clear to me

but the second part is blurry

define a function which inserts a child node to the specific node and if that new node has the identifier File it should be casted from type FOLDER* to type FILE*, the information of the node should be inserted in this function
THIS IS REALLY CONFUSING TO ME

```
typedef enum TYPE
{
    Folder,
    File
} TYPE;
typedef struct folder
{
    char *name;
    TYPE ident;
    struct folder *left,*right;
} FOLDER;
typedef struct file
{
    char*name;
    int data;
    TYPE ident;
} FILE;
```

Comment: Please, indent your code properly. Random spacing is really CONFUSING TO US.